# How can l solve my padding issue in my Unet?

Tags: pytorch, padding, tensor, unet-neural-network

Hello l am creating my Unet model. However l got weird issues they are a size missing on my third decoder line. l don't understand why. l am using a padding method in my UpBlock Class to get the same size. l got 2 tensors good torch.Size([2, 512, 139, 139]) torch.Size([2, 256, 267, 267]) but after l have this error message

RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 1. Expected size 519 but got size 518 for tensor number 1 in the list.

`class DoubleConv(nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
    
    super(DoubleConv, self).__init__()
    
    self.double_conv = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=2),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=2),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    )

def forward(self, out):
    
    x=self.double_conv(out)
    
    
    return x
```

class DownBlock(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, in_channels, out_channels):

```
    super(DownBlock, self).__init__()
    
    self.double_conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)
    self.down_sample = nn.MaxPool2d(2)

def forward(self, x):
    skip_out = self.double_conv(x)
    down_out = self.down_sample(skip_out)
    return (down_out, skip_out)
```

def pad_tensor(source, target):
"""
Pad source tensor to match target tensor size

```
:param source: tensor that need to get padding
:param target: tensor of the desired shape
:return: source tensor with shape equal to target
"""

diff_y = target.size()[2] - source.size()[2]
diff_x = target.size()[3] - source.size()[3]

source = F.pad(source, [diff_x // 2, diff_x - diff_x // 2, diff_y // 2, diff_y - diff_y // 2])
return source
```

class  UpBlock (nn.Module):
"""Upscaling then double conv"""

```
def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, up_sample_mode):
    super(UpBlock, self).__init__()
    if up_sample_mode == 'conv_transpose':
        self.up_sample = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, in_channels // 2, kernel_size=2, stride=2,  padding=1, output_padding=1)        
    elif up_sample_mode == 'bilinear':
        self.up_sample = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported `up_sample_mode` (can take one of `conv_transpose` or `bilinear`)")
    self.double_conv = DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels)

def forward(self, down_input, skip_input):
    
    down_input = self.up_sample(down_input)
    
    down_input = pad_tensor(down_input, skip_input)
    
    x = torch.cat([down_input, skip_input], dim=1)
    
    return self.double_conv(x)
```

class Siamese_UNet_Assement(nn.Module):
def **init**(self, out_classes, up_sample_mode='conv_transpose'):

```
    super(Siamese_UNet_Assement, self).__init__()
    
    self.up_sample_mode = up_sample_mode
    # Downsampling Path
    self.down_conv1 = DownBlock(3, 64)
    self.down_conv2 = DownBlock(64, 128)
    self.down_conv3 = DownBlock(128, 256)
    self.down_conv4 = DownBlock(256, 512)
    # Bottleneck
    self.double_conv = DoubleConv(512, 1024)
    # Upsampling Path
    self.up_conv4 = UpBlock(1024, 512, self.up_sample_mode)
    self.up_conv3 = UpBlock( 512, 256,self.up_sample_mode)
    self.up_conv2 = UpBlock(256,128,self.up_sample_mode)
    self.up_conv1 = UpBlock(128 , 64, self.up_sample_mode)
    # Final Convolution
    self.conv_last = nn.Conv2d(64, out_classes, kernel_size=1)

def forward(self, input1,input2):
    
    # Unet1
    
    # Encoder
    enc1_1, skip1_out1 = self.down_conv1(input1)
    print(skip1_out1.size())
    enc1_2, skip2_out1 = self.down_conv2(enc1_1)
    print(skip2_out1.size())
    enc1_3, skip3_out1 = self.down_conv3(enc1_2)
    print(skip3_out1.size())
    enc1_4, skip4_out1 = self.down_conv4(enc1_3)
    print(skip4_out1.size())

    bottleneck_1  = self.double_conv(enc1_4)
    print( bottleneck_1 .size())

    #Decoder
    dec4_1= self.up_conv4(bottleneck_1, skip4_out1)
    print(dec4_1.size())
    dec3_1= self.up_conv3(dec4_1, skip3_out1)
    print(dec3_1.size())
    dec2_1= self.up_conv2(dec3_1, skip2_out1)
    print(dec2_1.size())
    dec1_1 = self.up_conv1(dec2_1, skip1_out1)
    print(dec1_1.size())
    dec1_1 = self.conv_last(dec1_1)
    print(dec1_1.size())
    # Unet2
    
    # Encoder
    enc2_1, skip1_out2 = self.down_conv1(input2)
    enc2_2, skip2_out2 = self.down_conv2(enc2_1)
    enc2_3, skip3_out2 = self.down_conv3(enc2_2)
    enc2_4, skip4_out2 = self.down_conv4(enc2_3)
    bottleneck_2  = self.double_conv(enc2_4)
    
    #Decoder
    dec4_2= self.up_conv4(bottleneck_2 , skip4_out2)
    dec3_2_= self.up_conv3(dec4_2, skip3_out2)
    dec2_2= self.up_conv2(dec3_2_, skip2_out2)
    dec1_2 = self.up_conv1(dec2_2, skip1_out2)
    dec1_2 = self.conv_last(dec1_2)
    
    
    
    # Siamese
    output = torch.cat((dec1_1,dec1_2), 1)
    
    
    
    return output
```

`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your input dimension as well as it must be divisible multiple times by 2 depending on the amount of down blocks, otherwise you get an odd dimension that will create trouble when you upscale again.

As you downsample it 4 times, your input dimension should be divisible by `2^4=16`

Comment: thank you for your reply yes my inputs are divisible by 2

Comment: To clarify only 2 is not enough, you need a multiple of it **so that the bottleneck still has even dimension after downscaling**. Can you remove the skip connections and print the summary for the model to check? I think the image size must be divisible by at least 16, maybe even 32 after some research.

Comment: thank l found my bug l removed  padding=1 and  output_padding=1 in nn.ConvTranspose2d and l putted  padding ´=1 in Conv2d